# Reuse existing map instance for Leaflet directive

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm trying to add the [Leaflet Editable functionality](https://github.com/yohanboniface/Leaflet.Editable) to my current map which map is created by the leaflet directive. I'm getting the L.map instance with:

```
leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
  // where map is the Leaflet map instance
}
```

However the Leaflet editable needs to set `editable: true` when the map is created.

So, is there a way to create a L.map instance

```
var map = L.map('map', {editable: true});
```

and then attach it to the Leaflet angular directive?

UPDATE:

I tried to add a hook to Leaflet

```
L.Map.addInitHook(function () {
  this.whenReady(function () {
    this.editTools = new L.Editable(this, this.options.editOptions);
    console.log('L.map', this);
  });
}
```

It creates the editTools successfully but the

```
map.editTools.startPolyline();
```

is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `editable: true` to your defaults?

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    defaults: {
        editable: true
    },
    center: {
        lat: 51.505,
        lng: -0.09,
        zoom: 8
    }
});

<leaflet defaults="defaults" lf-center="center" height="480px" width="640px"></leaflet>
```

Comment: You can verify if it's really set by checking the options object of your map instance: `console.log(map.options.editable);`

Comment: adding the editable property to the defaults is not working at all. I've updated the question with my last attempt

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking like me to make an existing map editable

```
var map = L.map('map', {editable: true});
```

is the same as

```
var map = L.map('map');
map.editTools = new L.Editable(map);
```